# Mask tensorflow input data

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to apply a mask to each input feature in tensorflow. This is very easy to do if the mask is fixed - just define and apply it in the graph. The catch is, I want the mask to be varied during training - it will be slightly different for each training step. In fact, for each step, I have a function that returns a numpy array that represents the mask at every step.

After much trial and error and searching,I have found no way to apply this mask - as far as I am concerned, it is impossible to do, mandated by the properties of tensorflow to fix all the properties of the computation when the graph is built.

However, I am quite new to tensorflow so it is very possible that this is do-able, and even easy. Can anyone help me?

The pseudo-code would be:

```
    build graph with mask as placeholder
    Loop over training steps
        numpy_array = my_func(step_number)
        mask_placeholder = something(numpy_array)*
        Session.run([my graph(mask_placeholder)])*
```

The stars are where I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it would be so easy with just numpy. In fact, I had a situation where I wanted to do something which to me seemed trivial in numpy yet difficult in tensorflow. Specifically, I wanted to apply a mathematical function to certain elements of a tensor based on the value of those elements. EG:

`array_a[array_a > 0] = np.log(array_a + 1)[array_a > 0]`

Which translates into something like “A where A is greater than zero equals the log of A plus one where A is greater than zero”.

I didn’t succeed with it in tensorflow until I discovered **tf.py_func**. According to the description of py_func at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func,

> “Given a python function func, which takes numpy arrays as its inputs and returns numpy arrays as its outputs, wrap this function as an operation in a TensorFlow graph.”

So, to apply this to your situation, you could do something like

```
def tf_mask(the_tensor,the_mask):
    def np_mask(a,b):
        return a[b]
    return tf.py_func(np_mask, [the_tensor,the_mask], tf.float32)
```

or if you want to preserve the shape of the array, do something like

```
def tf_mask(the_tensor,the_mask):
    def np_mask(a,b):
        a[b == 0] = 0
        return a
    return tf.py_func(np_mask, [the_tensor,the_mask], tf.float32)
```

In summary, find a way to do it in numpy, and then use py_func. Numpy is pretty powerful and it is great that we can apparently wield that power in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the masking operation logic as part of the [TensorFlow graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework/). Specifically, [control flow operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/) like **tf.logical_and**, **tf.logical_or**, and **tf.case** allow you to select the desired data conditionally when the model is being run.

For example, the code below shows how to build a 4-element tensor based on the state of two training data or label inputs. You should be able to apply similar logic to your situation.

```
def const_v(val):
    return tf.constant(val, tf.float32)

def const_1():
    return const_v(1)

def const_0():
    return const_v(0)

def cond_and(cond_1, cond_2, val_1, val_2):
    return tf.logical_and(tf.equal(cond_1, val_1),
                          tf.equal(cond_2, val_2))

def vec4(c1, c2, c3, c4):
    return [const_v(c1), const_v(c2), const_v(c3), const_v(c4)]

# c1 c2 vector
# 1 1 [1, 0 , 0 ,0]
# 1 0 [0, 1, 0, 0]
# 0 1 [0, 0, 1, 0]
# 0 0 [0, 0, 0, 1]

def combined_conditions(cond_1, cond_2):
    return tf.stack(tf.case({cond_and(cond_1, cond_2, const_1(), const_1()): lambda: vec4(1, 0, 0, 0),
                    cond_and(cond_1, cond_2, const_1(), const_0()): lambda: vec4(0, 1, 0, 0),
                    cond_and(cond_1, cond_2, const_0(), const_1()): lambda: vec4(0, 0, 1, 0),
                    cond_and(cond_1, cond_2, const_0(), const_0()): lambda: vec4(0, 0, 0, 1)
                    }, default=lambda: vec4(0, 0, 0, 0), exclusive=True))
```

Comment: Im not sure that this will do the trick. Let me give a concrete example. Suppose my features are vectors of length 100,000. I do training with 100,000 steps. At each step, I want to mask the input feature with a mask vector of ones and zeros where the number of ones is just the training step number. The graph somehow has to know this number and create a new mask at each step. Note that the number it needs cannot be gleaned from the input data set itself.

Comment: I've never used them, but it appears you can get the training step from one of the [Training  Utility](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_guides/python/train#Training_Utilities) functions -- tf.train.get_global_step or tf.train.global_step. This plus the graph logic and some clever Python may solve your problem.